# How can I erase the '\' character from my string

Tags: java, json, regex, gson

I have a string which is a JSON array but it has characters that I don't want: some `"` and all of the `\`

There's the string :`["{\"id\":1,\"tel\":526833,\"date\":\"13/12\",\"message\":\"Test1\"}","{\"id\":2,\"tel\":526834,\"date\":\"13/12\",\"message\":\"Test2\"}"]`

and I want it to be like this: `[{"id":1,"tel":526833,"date":"13/12","message":"Test1"}","{"id":2,"tel":526834,"date":"13/12","message":"Test2"}]`

I get rid off the first and last `"` by doing

```
    jsonResp = jsonResp.replaceAll("\"[{]", "{");
    jsonResp = jsonResp.replaceAll("[}]\"", "}");
```

and now I need to erase the `\`, I try to do something like `jsonResp = jsonResp.replaceAll("\\", "");` but it my IDE says "Illegal/Unsupported escape sequence".

Here's my complete code if you want to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    SmsToSend smsToSend1 = new SmsToSend(1,526833,"Test1");
    SmsToSend smsToSend2 = new SmsToSend(2,526834,"Test2");
    jsonArray.add(new Gson().toJson(smsToSend1));
    jsonArray.add(new Gson().toJson(smsToSend2));
    String jsonResp = jsonArray.toString();
    System.out.println(jsonResp);
    jsonResp = jsonResp.replaceAll("\"[{]", "{");
    jsonResp = jsonResp.replaceAll("[}]\"", "}");
    jsonResp = jsonResp.replaceAll("\\", "");
    System.out.println(jsonResp);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

SOLUTION:

The problem was that `new Gson().toJson(smsToSend)` returns a String, so `jsonArray` was an array of string.
 I changed to `new Gson().toJsonTree(smsToSend)` which returns an Object and now it works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    SmsToSend smsToSend1 = new SmsToSend(1,526833,"Test1");
    SmsToSend smsToSend2 = new SmsToSend(2,526834,"Test2");
    jsonArray.add(new Gson().toJsonTree(smsToSend1));
    jsonArray.add(new Gson().toJsonTree(smsToSend2));
    String jsonResp = jsonArray.toString();
    System.out.println(jsonResp);
}
```

Comment: I think you should find out why the string is formatted like that. By removing characters, there's a high chance of messing up the formatting and making it un-parseable

Comment: What you have is JSON objects encoded as strings in a JSON array. First you should figure out why and where that's happening. If it can't be fixed at the source, parse it twice instead of trying to modify it by hand.

Comment: It looks like you have an array of JSON strings, ie each object has been stringified, put in an array and then the entire thing has been stringified again. You should be able to parse each string in the array as an object

Comment: Okay, I found a solution:
The problem was that `new Gson().toJson(smsToSend2)` returns a String, so the Array was an array of string
I change to `new Gson().toJsonTree(smsToSend2)` which returns an Object and now it works fine. Thank you very much

Comment: @Couldosh : You could answer your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

The problem was that new Gson().toJson(smsToSend) returns a String, so jsonArray was an array of string. I changed to new Gson().toJsonTree(smsToSend) which returns an Object and now it works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    SmsToSend smsToSend1 = new SmsToSend(1,526833,"Test1");
    SmsToSend smsToSend2 = new SmsToSend(2,526834,"Test2");
    jsonArray.add(new Gson().toJsonTree(smsToSend1));
    jsonArray.add(new Gson().toJsonTree(smsToSend2));
    String jsonResp = jsonArray.toString();
    System.out.println(jsonResp);
}
```